# Was there a purposeful dual use of the names Warlock and Magus in Marvel Comic Canon?

Tags: marvel, x-men, new-mutants

Reading through All-New X-Factor shortly after Annihilation caused me some confusion. The X-Factor books deal with the Technarch race with Magus as the King of Kvch and his son Warlock who is a member of the New Mutants. 
[image: Magus (Evil Technarch)][image: Warlock (Kind Technarch)]

Similarly, Adam Warlock was a character that Jim Starlin created as a reboot of Him when coming back to the Marvel Cosmic Universe in the mid-70's. Adam Warlock has a separate personality called the Magus. 
[image: Adam Warlock] [image: The Magus]

Warlock and Adam Warlock are aligned (most often) as good within the Marvel Canon while Magus and The Magus (Adam Warlock's alternate personality) are aligned (most often) as evil.

This is all very confusing and funny enough in the X-Factor Books Havok makes a tongue in cheek reference to it when asking Quicksilver information on Lorna Dane. I unfortunately cannot find the image, but will upload if I find it.

Was this duplicate naming intentional? I could not find any correlation of backstory through research.

Comment: And in both cases Warlock is the good character and Magus is the evil one.

Comment: @Boelabaal exactly my point. It seems to similar to be coincidence. Or just oversight?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### I am familiar with both sets of characters and their extensive back stories, I know of no relationships between the two. [Adam Warlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Warlock) predates the New Mutants' [Warlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warlock_(New_Mutants)) by about 20 years. They have completely different origins and power sets.

Adam Warlock's first appearance was in Fantastic Four #66 (1967). He was a genetically engineered lifeform created by a group of human scientists in a facility called the Beehive. Warlock was able to harness cosmic energy for feats of superhuman ability.

Warlock is a mechanical, sentient, shape-shifting extraterrestrial who first appeared in New Mutants #18 (August 1984). As a member of the **[Technarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technarchy)** he is able to infect other lifeforms with his bio-technical "virus" and absorb their life energy.

- The only comparison in their names might be the idea that power corrupts. A warlock would be a relatively young mage whereas a magus is an experienced mage who has mastered his magic through time.
- Adam Warlock's **[Magus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Warlock#The_Magus)** is a temporally-corrupted version of Adam Warlock who abandons the ideals of his younger self (from a parallel timeline) and becomes the ruler of the Universal Church, a galactic power in the future.
- The Technarch **[Magus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magus_(Technarchy))**, has tried time and time again to get his son, Warlock to embrace the Technarch creed of domination of species weaker than they are, but Warlock refuses and has battled to stay with his friends who are weaker than the Technarchs and organic to boot.

The odds are this is merely a coincidence in naming (unless the writers later reveal a connection) between the two sets of characters. In the current canon, there is no connection at all.

Comment: If I may comment opinion, one character could very well be a coincidence. Both? No friggin' way!